# QGIS 3.4 and loading raster from multiple variable NetCDF file

Tags: qgis-3, netcdf

Using QGIS version 3.4.4 when loading a NetCDF file out.nc which contains multiple variables on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install I encounter the following error:

`CRITICAL    Invalid Layer : Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: out.nc`

The same file load correctly on another 18.04 Ubuntu environment with more package setup. Unfortunately I cannot find which package is making the difference. The `libgdal` package seems to be the same on both environments.

Comment: Same issue on QGIS 3.6.1 on Windows (using OSGEO4W distribution)!

Comment: I had the same issue on 3.4 so upgraded to 3.6.1 to hopefully fix it, but still get the same error. Both installed with OSGEO4W.

Comment: There is now a ticket for this issue: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21783

Comment: Corresponding GitHub ticket: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29598